# Is it possible to show on open/forwarded session in KDE?

Tags: ssh, kde, forwarding, xforwarding

When I need to do some longer computation, I leave my computer unattended and just lock the screen. When I log in later to see how progress is going from a remote computer using ssh, it'd be great if I could have a open session as I left it.
Is it possible to remotely view the windows which we're on display when the desktop was locked?

Say I log in from another computer to my computer using ssh -Y and leave the forwarded session on that computer open, can I somehow view from a third computer the windows which are forwarded to the the other computer?

Answer (score 0):

There are already existing tools for that. Unfortunately, they aren't part of the base X distribution, but they are related tools and opensource.

The simplest thing is the vnc. That enables for you to remotely handle your desktop.

There are complexer things as well, they are not always opensource, for example teamviewer.

Both of their server and client side supports win, linux and osx as well.